# Append lines of user input to a list passed to tar

Tags: bash, tar

Hello I want to create a dynamic list of files chosen by user in my script. After that I want to use list in tar commend. (I want to add a few files (chosen by user) to tar archives)

```
!#/bin/bash
while [ $A != "exit" ]; do
read FILE     #user types correct filename         

#files will be chosen via dialog menu but it isn't important now


echo "If you don't want to choose more files type 'exit'
read A
done

tar -cvf FILE1 FILE2 FILE3 ........
```

I think that I should use another loop but I don't know how to connect this loop with variable FILE inside loop (while) and with how to connect this loop with tar

Comment: BTW, a shebang is `#!`, not `!#`

Comment: ...as another aside, all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell itself; your own names should have at least one lower-case character. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable. ("The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.")

Answer (score 0):

See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for guidance on reading content into the shell line-by-line, and [BashFAQ #5](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) for an introduction to arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files=( )                          # initialize an empty array
while IFS= read -r line; do        # as long as there is input...
  [[ $line = exit ]] && break      # ...and it is not the word "exit"...
  files+=( "$line" )               # ...append that input to the array.
done

tar -czf file.tar.gz "${files[@]}" # then tack that array onto a tar command
```